# Android Studio - Unresolved reference: truth

Tags: google-truth

I am trying to include the Google Truth framework in my project for testing. I followed the documentation on how to get the project setup.

This is from my app's build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.2-alpha01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.43'
}
```

The syncing process completes successfully.

Then I attempt to run a local unit test for example:

```
import org.junit.Test
import com.google.common.truth.Truth.*

class CustomExampleUnitTest {

    @Test
    fun testBlank_isCorrect() {
        assertThat("".isBlank()).isTrue()
    }
}
```

I get a Kotlin compiler error: Unresolved reference: truth

There are a couple of things to note:

- When I attempt to use a method related to Truth by just starting to type, there is no suggestions for any of those methods. This is without manually adding the import statement, but Android Studio has always done that automatically when I choose the appropriate method from the suggested ones, so this was the first odd things I noticed.
- When the above mentioned did not work, I manually did the import and as I was typing what to import, I did get suggestions for com.google.common.truth.Truth... which showed me that at least the jar file was somewhere to be found. After this manual import, the Android Studio then started suggesting methods from Truth as I expected before.

So after going through the steps above, I tried to run the test and I still get the unresolved issue.

Could anyone please try to shed some light on this? Has anyone encountered this. I would be really grateful for any kind of help!

Answer (score 26):

If your tests are in the `androidTest` directory then you need

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.43'
```

but if your tests are in the `test` directory then you need

```
testImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.43'
```

Answer (score 3):

Blockquote

If your use kotlin use

testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.3.0'

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the Truth library is not auto-suggested from Android Studio and IDEA (I still don't know why). When typing `Truth`, it lists out like this
[image: auto correct with Truth]

or when typing `import com.google.`, `common` sub-package name doesn't even show
[image: auto correct with import com.google.]

However, when I run by typing full import, it works like a miracle.

```
import com.google.common.truth.Truth
```

[image: after force import truth]

(it takes me a morning to figure out this mysterious)